# Drupal 7 - Saving User ID in a Content Type field

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need to write the Drupal User ID on a int field of a custom content type, after submitting the form. I believe I have to use hook_node_presave to do this. But I'm new on Drupal, and extremely new on PHP, so, I have some basic questions...

1. Where, in my Drupal installation, I have to insert the hook code? In what file? A new one? What directory? I want this code totally theme-agnostic, upgrade-agnostic, and newbie-agnostic...
2. Can anybody spend a bit of your precious time writing an example of code for this task?
3. As already mentioned, I'm very newbie. So, detailed explanations are very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to write a Drupal [module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules)

Basically, you need to add a folder and some required files in there.  Then you go into the administration and turn the module on.  Drupal will automatically start processing the hooks you have specified in that module once its turned on.  More info [here](http://drupal.org/node/1075072)

Most code changes are done this way in the Drupal world.  The other place is to override theme settings, but as you say, u wish to make it theme agnostic.

Comment: You mean I should create an entire module to perform just a value assignment to one field? This is not about laziness, it seems like to use a bazooka to kill a mosquito. Drupal has not a flyswatter to do this?

Comment: I believe so - I felt the same way about Drupal and prefer not to develop in it now :)  I could be wrong as I did not get far enough into Drupal before giving up on it.

On the other hand, Drupal is enforcing that all changes are modular and can be reverted.   I believe there's some merit in it.  It works on a system of module overrides and discourages you from hacking the core code (although you certainly can just to get it done).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your attention, badunk!

Answer (score 0):

All nodes are automatically saved with the user id of the user who created the node, so if your intention is to know who created the node, simply look at the $node->uid.   No need to save an extra field in your content type.  Hope that helps.